# MongoDB remove all elements from the array inside one document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to delete all elements from an array in my document..

I have an array of object id's
[image]

My model looks like this:

```
const TypeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ISOklasifikacija: { type: String, requred: false },
  profilUIC: { type: String, requred: false },
  certificateId: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Certificates",
      required: false,
    },
  ],
});
```

My query for clearing the array is:

```
 let type = await Type.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        _id: req.params.typeId,
      },
      {
        $set: { certificateId: [] },
      },
      { multi: true }
    );

    console.log(type);
```

It nevers clear the array. In console I get: **null** and this id exists which I am passing in

Thanks for help

Comment: Print out the `req.params.typeId`

Comment: Oh god.. I had a typo in my type route.. god dammit :D thank you!

Comment: Now everything works good